# Jquerymobile form popping up on Android on Motorola

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, motorola

MY jquery mobile app m.dosomething.org works fine on Iphone but on Android and Motorola keeps popping up keyboard on the form. It works fine with Android on my HTC. I tried with different Jquery mobile versions but does not seem to work for now. Also with out the android SDK , its kind of tough to test.  Is this a common issue for Androids on Motorola ? Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you trying to say that when you focus on a field in the form, the keyboard pops up and you don't want this to happen? "Android on HTC" or "Android on Motorola" doesn't give anyone enough information about Android to be able to debug.

Comment: Yes, when the user is on the signup page and clicks on the textbox the form just rolls up and with every event when the user tries to type, it keeps rolling up and it is not possible to see the field that one is trying to type in. It does not happen on the Android version 1.5 on HTC but does happen on the latest Android versions on a Motorola phone.

Comment: Yeah that is happening to me, definitely. I think its rolling up to accomodate for the height of the keyboard or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my Jquery mobile version to beta and Jquery version to 1.6. That seemed to have taken care of that issue for now. 
Thanks for the help